# URL rewriting - Rule seems ok but completely ignored IIS 7

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7

I want to redirect request going to "oldSubDomain" to "newSubDomain".
Here what the URL looks like :

https://oldSubDomain.myWebSite.com
should go to
https//newSubDomain.myWebSite.com

Here the rule as it has been added to the web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="NewSubDomain">
            <match url=".*oldSubDomain.*" />  
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://newSubDomain.myWebSite.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />  
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Rule seems OK, but when I go to "https://oldSubDomain.myWebSite.com", the rule seems being ignored and I get the oldsubdomain pages...
I am using IIS7.0 and the web application is done using MVC 4.5.

An idea ? Anyone ? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999735/iis-7-url-rewrite-match-url) answer. Basically it appears that the only portion you will be given is the portion relative to your web.config file. It is possible that if you have the web.config defined in the mywebsite.com directory that you are only getting the `myWebSite.com` portion for matching.

Comment: So, if I understand well the link, my request is impossible :-(. As I want to change the subdomain name and this one is not available in the web.config file.

Comment: If that is indeed what is causing your issue then you would need to create an application on the IIS root at https://oldSubDomain with a web config or go into IIS and set the rule there in which case IIS will create a web config in the root for you.